# ThreadLocal: why changes made by one thread is visible in other thread

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Consider following code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        
        Set<Integer> set=new HashSet<>();
       set.add(1);
        
        ThreadLocal<Set> var1=new ThreadLocal<>();
        
        //THREAD1
        Runnable r=()->{
                    
            var1.set(set);

            for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
             System.out.println("Thread ID:"+Thread.currentThread()+":  "+var1.get());
            };

        Thread th=new Thread(r);
        th.start();
        
        //THREAD2
        Thread th1=new Thread(()-> {
                
            var1.set(set);
            
            var1.get().remove(1); //removing 1 from this thread copy of set.
            var1.get().add(2);    //adding 2 to this thread copy of set 
            
            for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
             System.out.println("Thread ID:"+Thread.currentThread()+":  "+var1.get());
             
        });
        th1.start();
        
        
    }
```

Output:

```
Thread ID:Thread[Thread-0,5,main]:  [2]
Thread ID:Thread[Thread-0,5,main]:  [2]
Thread ID:Thread[Thread-0,5,main]:  [2]
Thread ID:Thread[Thread-0,5,main]:  [2]
Thread ID:Thread[Thread-0,5,main]:  [2]
Thread ID:Thread[Thread-0,5,main]:  [2]
Thread ID:Thread[Thread-0,5,main]:  [2]
Thread ID:Thread[Thread-0,5,main]:  [2]
Thread ID:Thread[Thread-0,5,main]:  [2]
Thread ID:Thread[Thread-0,5,main]:  [2]
Thread ID:Thread[Thread-1,5,main]:  [2]
Thread ID:Thread[Thread-1,5,main]:  [2]
Thread ID:Thread[Thread-1,5,main]:  [2]
Thread ID:Thread[Thread-1,5,main]:  [2]
Thread ID:Thread[Thread-1,5,main]:  [2]
Thread ID:Thread[Thread-1,5,main]:  [2]
Thread ID:Thread[Thread-1,5,main]:  [2]
Thread ID:Thread[Thread-1,5,main]:  [2]
Thread ID:Thread[Thread-1,5,main]:  [2]
Thread ID:Thread[Thread-1,5,main]:  [2]
```

Why changes made by Thread2(i.e. removing of 1 and addition of 2) is visible to thread1 also? What will be the ideal use case here?

Comment: The `ThreadLocal` is created in the main thread before starting the subthreads, so there's only one instance.

Comment: @JimGarrison, There _should_ be only one instance of a `ThreadLocal` That's the whole point. A `ThreadLocal<t>` effectively is a `Map<threadID,t>` where the `get()` and `set(v)` methods use the caller's thread ID as the key.

Answer (score 2):

In learning to program, you may have heard the metaphor that a variable is  a box with a name where you can store something. If you want to look at that thing later, you find the box with the correct name and look inside.

A thread local is like a magic box. Its contents depend on who is looking. Each thread can put a *different thing* in the *same box,* and access it again later.

In your example, you had two threads, each with their own view of the magic box that you named `var1`. But, each of these these threads put the *same object* into the box—the aptly-named `set` object.

Because there is only one instance of the set used by both threads, the actions of each thread interfere with each other. Using a thread local this way is pointless; it's equivalent to each thread accessing the variable `set` directly.

A more useful application of `ThreadLocal` would assign distinct values to the thread local in each thread. In your example, this means creating another `HashSet` instance inside each `Runnable`. This maintains the isolation of each value to one thread, and avoids the concurrency bugs you have in your code.

Under the hood, a `ThreadLocal` is essentially a map where keys are threads, and values are the value assigned to the reference in that thread.

I am not sure there is an "ideal" use case for `ThreadLocal`; I see it as a tool for workarounds when the ideal is not possible. I see them as a necessary evil, a last resort. But, for example, you could use a `ThreadLocal` to pass extra data up and down the stack when it can't be passed as method parameters.

Comment: Re, "copy of the value...copy of the variable..." IMO this could be confusing to a newbie. It would be better if you started with an explanation of the difference between a `Set` _instance,_ and a `Set` _variable_ (holds a reference to a Set instance.) That's a concept with which a lot of Java newbies seem to struggle. Once they understand that distinction, then it's easier to explain how a `ThreadLocal` is a collection of _references,_ and how the OP's program assigns the _same_ reference to each slot.